# strong-pm cluster more than I set

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am noticing a starnge case. Though I had set 20 clusters, slc ctl status shows more than 20 cluster if i run slc ctl soft-restart shaadiapi, it again reset to 20 but after some time it again shows more than 20.

I am wondering what could be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Doing `slc ctl soft-restart` will restart each worker, one at a time, until they have all been replaced.

In order to do this without causing downtime for all cluster sizes, this is done by first starting a new worker, and then killing an old one. In other words, your cluster size will got 20, 21, 20, 21, 20, 21, etc. instead of 20, 19, 20, 19, 20, 19, etc.

This behaviour is particularly important when using a cluster size of 1 or 2, as killing an old worker before replacing it can have a significant impact on the application's ability to process requests.

Comment: question is is not what is soft restart... I want to understand why there  r more than 20 clusters when I had set 20 only. and each time there are more than 23 clusters even after 30 minutes I run soft restart.

Comment: Sorry, I must have misread the original question. Perhaps this would be better asked as an issue on https://github.com/strongloop/strong-pm/issues